# count by element in array bigquery

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I have a table containing a column of INT64 arrays of length 5, containing values 1-5. For each row, I want to translate the contents of the array into 5 values which reflect the frequency of each value 1-5 in the row's array. From that, I'm aggregating by sum for each column.

E.g. [1, 4, 5, 5, 4]

Should yield

| one | two | three | four | five |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 |

```
  SUM((
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      UNNEST(arr) AS x
    WHERE
      x = 5)) AS five,
  SUM((
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      UNNEST(arr) AS x
    WHERE
      x = 4)) AS four,
  SUM((
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      UNNEST(arr) AS x
    WHERE
      x = 3)) AS three,
  SUM((
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      UNNEST(arr) AS x
    WHERE
      x = 2)) AS two,
  SUM((
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      UNNEST(arr) AS x
    WHERE
      x = 1)) AS one
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can simplify it by calling `UNNEST` only once and then process particular value:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(x= 1, 1, 0)) AS one,
  SUM(IF(x= 2, 1, 0)) AS two,
  SUM(IF(x= 3, 1, 0)) AS three,
  SUM(IF(x= 4, 1, 0)) AS four,
  SUM(IF(x= 5, 1, 0)) AS five
FROM
  UNNEST(arr) AS x
```

You call `UNNEST` once for your array and as you process values, you increment particular columns according to current value.

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, I would recommend [`unnest` in a lateral join](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/arrays#flattening_arrays), and then [`countif()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#countif) for conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    countif(x = 1) cnt_1,
    countif(x = 2) cnt_2,
    countif(x = 3) cnt_3,
    countif(x = 4) cnt_4,
    countif(x = 5) cnt_5
from mytable t
cross join unnest(t.arr) as x
```